# Width overiding justify content

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native

I have 2 `<views>` in a main `<view>` I set the second view to `90%` width , the width is `90%` of the screen size but it does not center on the page and I have set the `justifycontents` to center,when I remove the `width` property, the view centers,  Please what am I doing wrong

```
return (
            <View style={BackStyles.main}>
                <View style={BackStyles.container}>
                    <TextInput placeholder="Search for your herbs..."
                               underlineColorAndroid={'transparent'} style={BackStyles.textBox}/>
                </View>
                <View style={BackStyles.herb_box}>
                    <Text>values</Text></View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
}

const BackStyles = StyleSheet.create({
herb_box: {
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    borderRadius: 7,
    marginTop: 20,
    // alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    margin: 'auto',
    width: '90%',
},
main: {
    flexDirection: 'column',
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#E2E2E2',
    // justifyContent: 'center',
},
container: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'flex-start',
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    //   flex: 1,
    //  backgroundColor: '#E2E2E2',
    marginTop: 20,
    //  width: '100%'
},
textBox: {
    flex: 1,
    height: 45,
    padding: 4,
    //  textAlignVertical: 'top',
    paddingLeft: 20,
    // marginRight: 5,
    flexGrow: 1,
    //  fontSize: 18,
    color: '#000',
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    // textAlign: 'center'
 },
```

Comment: Make sure the display on the view is set to block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set **the marginHorizontal** to **5%** Update the herbBox to this:

```
herb_box: {
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    borderRadius: 7,
    marginTop: 20,
    marginHorizontal:"5%",
    margin: 'auto',
    width: '90%',
},
```